# Why does it make a difference when I add the Domain-Property at Cookies in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I just lost about an hour because of an unexpected behaviour with creating cookies in asp.net.

First version:

```
HttpCookie cookie1=new HttpCookie("myCookie","myValue1");
cookie1.Domain="www.myurl.com";
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

Second Version:

```
HttpCookie cookie2=new HttpCookie("myCookie","myValue2");
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

As you can see in the second version I just did not enter the Domain information. When I analyze the client cookies in my browser, BOTH cookies have been saved under the same domain (including the subdomain). I would have expected that the second cookie overrides the first cookie and not adds another one with the same name.

What is the difference between those two cookies? Why is it saved twice?

Comment: Is your real question 'Why', as opposed to 'How can I correct this'?

Comment: The real question is "what is the difference" between those two cookies. As I know the difference, there is nothing to correct (I just save both cookies)

Comment: are you sure that the subdomain is the same, and the path is the same ?

Comment: Yes. Same Subdomain, no Path